# Нужна запятая перед словом «также»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Можем также съездить куда-то ещё.*

Answer (score 2):

**Можем также съездить куда-то ещё.**

Запятая не нужна, *также* ― это не вводное слово, а присоединительный союз.